# Request "Unauthorized" with socket.io and node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I try to deploy a web app. But i got a problem using a chat in my web site. It's work perfectly fine in local but not online. I got a response 401 "Unauthorized" when i try to access to my chat. I use socket.io

Here is the code :

Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const security = require('./middleware/security');
const userRouter = require('./routes/user');
const AnnonceRouter = require('./routes/annonce');
const securityRouter = require('./routes/security');
const commentRouter = require('./routes/comment');
const mailRouter = require('./routes/mail')
const path = require('path');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

var chat = require('https').createServer(app)
var io = module.exports.io = require('socket.io').listen(chat)
const SocketManager = require('./SocketManager')
io.on('connection', SocketManager)

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('../client/build')); // serve the static react app
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(bodyparser.json());
  app.use(security.verifyToken);
  app.use('/', securityRouter);
  app.use('/annonce', AnnonceRouter);
  app.use('/user', userRouter);
  app.use('/comment', commentRouter);
  app.use('/mail', mailRouter);
  app.get(/^\/(?!api).*/, (req, res) => { // don't serve api routes to react app
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
  })
  console.log('Serving React App...');
};

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.error(`Node ${isDev ? 'dev server' : 'cluster worker '+process.pid}: listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

a part of my layout.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import { USER_CONNECTED, LOGOUT } from '../Events'
import LoginForm from './LoginForm'
import ChatContainer from './chats/ChatContainer'

const socketUrl = "https://teachonline.herokuapp.com"
export default class Layout extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        socket:null,
        user:null
      };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.initSocket()
    }

    /*
    *   Connect to and initializes the socket.
    */
    initSocket = ()=>{
        const socket = io(socketUrl)

        socket.on('connect', ()=>{
            console.log("Chat Connected");
        })

        this.setState({socket})
    }
```

When i try to access to my chat here is the logs in Heroku

2019-08-26T22:25:04.828537+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
2019-08-26T22:25:04.828550+00:00 app[web.1]: at verifyToken (/app/server/middleware/security.js:13:29)

Here is my security.js

```
const verifyJWTToken = require('../libs/auth').verifyToken;

const access_routes = ["/login_check", "/user", "/mail/send", "/landing-page", "/security/login", "/chat","/socket.io"]

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    if(access_routes.indexOf(req.path) > -1) {
        next();
    } else {
        const auth = req.get('Authorization');
        if(!auth || !auth.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
            res.sendStatus(401);
        }
        verifyJWTToken(auth.replace("Bearer ", ""))
        .then((decodedToken) => {
            req.user = decodedToken;
            next();
        })
        .catch((error) => res.status(400).send({
            error: "JWT TOKEN invalid",
            details: error
        }));
    }
}

module.exports = {
    verifyToken
}
```

if it's needed the auth.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const JWT_SECRET = "MaBelleJonquille";

const createToken = function (user = {}) {
    return jwt.sign({
        payload: {
            userName: user.user_name
        }
    }, JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "7d",
        algorithm: "HS256"
    });
};

const verifyToken =  function (token) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET, (err, decodedToken) => {
        if(err || !decodedToken) {
            reject(err);
        }

        resolve(decodedToken);
    }));
};

//fonction pour hasher le password rentré

module.exports = {
    createToken,
    verifyToken
}
```

The example of a request

```
let myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Content-type", "application/json");
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('tokenJWT'));
            fetch (URL + localStorage.getItem('user_name'),
            {
                method:'GET',
                mode: "cors",
                headers : myHeaders
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                data.user_skill.map(x => {
                    this.skill.push({label: x, value: x});
                });
            })
            .catch(error => (error));
```

I tried severals things found in the internet but none of them worked for me, so if you have any idea of what am i doing wrong, i'm listening.

Thanks for reading me

Comment: please make sure that you are using https on production, and installed ssl correctly ,if you did that please open chrome dev tools / network tab and tell me which request you are get this response on it, also the payload and header,

Comment: There is no authorization header on your API call, so this is always true: if(!auth || !auth.startsWith('Bearer ')). What API call are you making and what are the headers?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your repplies. I think you are totaly right.
this is my request : https://teachonline.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MpKCJce where i get a 401. And as you said i never put my header with the token

I edit my code just to put an example of the request i made with other stuff. How can i made the one with the socket.io ?

Comment: It's the first time i use StackOverflow to ask some questions, so tell me if it's a better way for me to give you all the things you need to understand everything